# create array of object in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Is my approach wrong?

How I can push new array of Object once button will trigger?

**Object**

this is the my object.

```
query = [
 {
  a: [],
  b: [],
  c: [],
  d: []
 }
],[
 {
  a: [],
  b: [],
  c: [],
  d: []
 }
],.....;
```

I am looking for answer to get new object, not over ride the object array.
How to achieve this on submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can push object in query object

```
query.push([{
 a: [],
 b: [],
 c: [],
 d: [],
}]);
```

Comment: thanks, can we make a limit of push, let say max 5 time we can push

Comment: @FaisalJanjua : Check the length before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

add a counter and check that value before pushing like so:

```
if(counter < 5) {           
        query.push([{
                      a: [],
                      b: [],
                      c: [],
                      d: [],
                   }]);
    counter++;
 }
```

Comment: No need of a counter here, just use the *length* property of the array i.e `query.length < 5`